# awk - IF column $1 is not equal to the previous column $1 then print entire previous line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to write an awk program on Linux, where if the string in the first column is different to the string in the first column of the previous line, it will print the entire previous line.

Another way to put this is whenever the first column is equal, print the entire last line of matched columns and discard the previous one that is equal.

I used this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" } $1==last{next} {last=$1} {print last}' test.txt
```

But I guess it is only printing the previous line's first column. How can I print the entire previous line?

My input file, `test.txt`, looks like this:

```
818522;"Joey";
817399;"john";
817399;"CCE";
817399;"smith";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
817400;
817400;
818000;"ODC";
890021;
890021;
890021;"rachel";
890021;"monica"
```

Desired Output:

```
818522;"Joey";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
818000;"ODC";
890021;"monica"
```

Comment: Save the last field and the last line...

Comment: Can we assume the file will be sorted on the first column?

Comment: Please don't multi-post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/74164469/1745001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F';' '$1 != l1 && l1 != "" { print l0 };
             {l1 = $1; l0 = $0};
             END {if ($1 != $l1) {print}}' test.txt 
818522;"Joey";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
818000;"ODC";
890021;"monica"
```

The `-F';'` option sets awk's input field separator (`FS`) to a semi-colon.  awk automatically splits each input line on `FS` and assigns the fields to $1, $2, $3, ....., $n.

Variables `l1` and `l0` are used to hold the first field (`$1`) and the entire line (`$0`).

For the most part, `awk` scripts are a series of `PATTERN { ACTION }` rules - if PATTERN evaluates as true, the ACTION is executed. PATTERN can be anything that evaluates as either true or false (regex matches, variable comparisons, calculations, etc).  ACTION can be any awk code statement(s).  These rules are repeated for each line of input.  Note that either PATTERN or ACTION can be optional - if PATTERN is missing, it is treated as evaluating to true and the ACTION is always executed.  If ACTION is missing, the default action is `print` (i.e. print the current input line). This is only a very brief and simplified summary, for more details read the awk documentation (e.g. `man awk` or, if you are using GNU awk, `info awk`.  There's also the O'Reilly [sed & awk](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sed-awk/1565922255/) book by Dale Dougherty & Arnold Robbins).

The first line of the awk script tests if the current line's `$1` is **not equal** to both `l1` **and** the empty string.  If both tests are true, it prints the last input line, `l0`.  On the first line of input, `l1` will always be empty (because the 2nd line of the script hasn't executed yet, so no value has been assigned to it), so nothing will be printed (`l0` would also be empty, anyway, so printing it would just output an empty line).

The second line of the awk script unconditionally sets `l1` and `l0` from the current input line.

The script repeats those two lines of code for each line of input.

When there is no more input, the main script loop ends and the `END {...}` block is executed.  It prints the current input line (i.e. the last line of input) - currently only if `$1 != l1` but on reflection (and some brief testing), it would probably work just as well without that test, just `END {print}`.

Comment: your answer works. thank you for fast reply. If it's not too much to ask, could you explain each step of the awk command?

Answer (score 4):

Your description doesn't match your output, so I am a bit confused. Based on your description, the expected output should be:

```
818522;"Joey";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
818000;"ODC";
```

You wouldn't print any of the `890021` lines because they are last, so they will never have a different first field than the next line. If this is indeed what you want, you can do this:

```
$ awk -F';' '{ 
                if($1!=last && prevLine){ print prevLine } 
                { last=$1; prevLine=$0 }
             }' file
818522;"Joey";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
818000;"ODC";
```

If you also want to add an exception for the last bunch of lines, try something like this:

```
$ awk -F';' '{ 
              if($1!=last && prevLine){
                print prevLine; 
                lastPrinted=last
              } 
              {
                last=$1; 
                prevLine=$0
              }
             }
             END{ 
                if($1 != lastPrinted){ print }
             }' file 
818522;"Joey";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
818000;"ODC";
890021;"monica"
```

The idea is quite straightforward: if the first field is not the same as `last` and the `prevLine` variable is defined (so we don't print the first line), then we print the previous line (`prevLine`) and save the first field of the previous line (`last`) in the variable `lastPrinted`.

Then, for all lines, we set `last` to the 1st field and `prevLine` to the current line. Finally, when we reach the end of the file (`END{}`) we print the line if its 1st field is different from the 1st field we last printed for (`lastPrinted`).

Answer (score 2):

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs ';' -N --ragged unsparsify then tail -n 1 -g 1 file
818522;Joey;
817399;Ron;
817400;;
818000;ODC;
890021;monica;
```

This uses [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to read the data as header-less CSV with `;` as the field separator. The input is allowed to have a varying number of fields per record.

We start by filling the non-existent fields in each record with empty values using the `unsparsify` operation, and then we use `tail` to get the last value of each group when grouping by the first field.

The output will be quoted if needed, or you may add `--quote-all` to quote all fields.

Comment: Miller's a good tool for this kind of thing, but what version are you running?  With miller 6.4.0-1 on debian sid, I'm getting only an error message: `mlr: mlr: CSV header/data length mismatch 3 != 2 at filename test.txt row 6.`

Comment: @cas Thanks for that! I'm using my system's default Miller 5.10.2, but forgot to test with later versions. Adding `--ragged` makes it work universally. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The above command gives `mlr: empty CSV key at file` and `mlr: option --ragged not recognised`. Now I've changed it to `mlr --nidx --fs ';' unsparsify then tail -n 1 -g 1 file` in `Miller 5.3.0`. This works. Therefore upvoted.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh Yes, there has definitely been a number of changes in Miller relating to how CSV data with variable number of fields per records are handled and accepted (or not accepted). Version 5.3.0 is quite old though and any current Linux should have a newer version by now (note that Ubuntu 18 has soon reached its end of life).

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed will cope.

```
sed -r 'N;/^([^;]+;).*\1/!P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -t ';' -g 1 last 2 <file
```

`-t ;` sets semicolon as field separator.

`last 2` prints last value of the field 2.

`-g 1` is short form of `groupby 1`.

This command is taken from [datamash alternative one-liners](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/alternatives). See 'Last value of each group'.